# Spring jpaRepository Query to find records in lists IGNORE CASE and using LIKE CONCAT

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, bigdata

I would like to make a Query in JpaRepository in Spring. 
For example i give 2 lists of Strings:

```
titles{"Wit", "Bbi"}
authors{"sa","kIEn"}
```

and I receive list of authors from db:

```
1{"Sapkowski"}
2{"Tolkien"}
```

Is it possible with a query like this? something like adding
LIKE CONCAT('%', UPPER(:tag), '%') ignoring cases, etc. but to check a whole list?

```
@Query("SELECT b.author FROM BookDB b WHERE b.title IN :titles AND b.author IN :authors")

List<String> findAuthorsByTitlesAndAuthors(@Param("titles ") List<String> titles ,
        @Param("authors") List<String> authors);
```

Or maybe method names? I cannot figure it out...
I would like to make it in the best way bearing in mind performance in a bigger data and code readability.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A case-insensitive search query is possible with JPA Repository methods, something like: `findAuthorsByTitlesIgnoreCaseAndAuthorsIgnoreCase`

Comment: The problem is that I also need to query parts of words and I query list of them :/